# Filtrar elementos en Python

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo una función que toma como parámetros una lista de números enteros y ademas dos números enteros extras. La función debe devolver una nueva lista conteniendo los números de la lista pasada como primer parámetro cuyos valores se encuentren en el rango comprendido entre el segundo y tercer parámetro (ambos incluidos). El codigo que he podido hacer es el siguiente, pero no sé como continuar: El CÓDIGO ME DA ERROR PERO NO SE INTERPRETARLO

```
import number_functions

numbers = [1, 4, 7, 8, 3, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
start = 4
end = 10
filtered_numbers = number_functions.filter_numbers(numbers, start, end)
print(filtered_numbers)


def filter_numbers(numbers, start, end):
    new_list = []
    rango = (start, end +1)
    for i, numbers in rango:
        if i in numbers is in range(start, end+1):
            new_list = [i]
            return new_list
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que puegues el error para poder identificarlo más rapido.

Comment: tu dices: *El CÓDIGO ME DA ERROR PERO NO SE INTERPRETARLO*, ¿Cual es ese mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes la idea, pero te has confundido en muchas cosas. Te pego el código completo y más abajo te explico la razón de cada cambio.

```
def filter_numbers(numbers, start, end):
    new_list = []
    for i in numbers:
        if i >= start and i <= end:
            new_list.append(i)
    return new_list

numbers = [1, 4, 7, 8, 3, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15]
start = 4
end = 10
filtered_numbers = filter_numbers(numbers, start, end)
print(filtered_numbers)
```

Primero eliminé el import y moví el def arriba, porque para llamar a la función (cuando haces `filtered_numbers = filter_numbers(numbers, start, end)`), el intérprete tiene que haber visto la función declarada anteriormente.

Luego, tu "rango" no es más que una tupla (similar a una lista, pero inmutable). Python no puede adivinar qué quieres hacer cuando haces `for i, numbers in rango:`. En cambio, si creas un `for i in numbers`, le estás diciendo que por cada **elemento "i"** en el iterable **numbers**, hacer lo siguiente:

```
if i >= start and i <= end:
```

Esto debería ser auto explanatorio. Si el **elemento i** es mayor o igual al mínimo, y menor o igual al máximo, hacer lo siguiente. Otra forma (matemática) de verlo es:

```
i ϵ [start,end]
```

`new_list.append(i)` significa "insertar elemento i en la lista *new_list*

Y finalmente, puse el return al final, porque si retornas dentro del `for`, la función va a retornar en la primera pasada, y no es el resultado que quieres (quieres pasar por toda la lista numbers)